# What is the value stored in new object when created?

Tags: java, string, object, memory, memory-leaks

When we use:

```
String s = new String("abc");
```

to make a `String` object.

`s` will be stored in stack and will refer to new object and a new object will be created in heap while the literal will be in String Constant pool.

Now the question is what would be the value of the new object will it have the reference of the memory of "abc" in String pool constant or it will carry "abc" as the value?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking whether `s` will be a reference to the object in the constant pool?

Comment: Could you elaborate it more?

Comment: @Yohannes Just wanted to ask will the object which is created by new operator be pointing to literal abc or it will be having abc as its value.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just want to know what the new String would be holding whether it will be the memory address of literal stored in String Constant Pool or it will be carrying value abc itself.

Comment: But what do you mean by "carrying value abc"? You need to be *really precise* about what you're asking, or we can't really answer it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Apologies for strechung it too long.
I just want to know what value  new String() will be holding in the heap memory.

Comment: It looks like arshajii has answered you then... but it really depends on you knowing about the internal structure of `String`.

Comment: @JonSkeet So it means that literal abc object will be unrefrenced and the heap object will have original value stored ?

Answer (score 1):

We can look at the [`String` constructor](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l151):

```
public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

Notice that the `value` of the original string is not copied, so both the newly created string and `"abc"` will refer to the same underlying array of characters.